# UITextView Links inside of UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextview

So i've got a `UITextView` the contents of which are loaded in from an RTF file. I have the data detector type set to `UIDataDetectorTypeLink`, it looks as follows:

```
cell.articleView.attributedText = attrString;
cell.articleView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;
cell.articleView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
cell.articleView.selectable = YES;
```

My attributed string is:

```
NSAttributedString *attrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path]
                                                                  options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSRTFTextDocumentType} documentAttributes:Nil error:nil];
```

In the cell the links load, they're colored blue etc, but clicking on them does nothing. Im assuming its because the Cell is intercepting the clicks, but I'm not sure how to circumvent that.

Comment: Perhaps the attributed string generator from RTF creates links incorrectly. Could you reproduce the issue and print the attributed string in the debugger? You can also implement the delegate of the text view and see what URL is passed in `textView:shouldInteractWithURL:inRange:`.

Comment: @LeoNatan the link is showing up when I log out the attributed string, but the delegate method never gets called. Not sure how to pass along the touches to the textview.